# websites with good and clean HTML/CSS to learn from

Tags: css

I currently have some modest HTML/CSS Know-How and want to improve from there.

I found out for myself that the best way is to get the HTML/CSS from an existing Website and to rebuild it from scratch and do some old fashioned learning by doing: why is this element needed, what happens if I remove it in firebug, etc...

But like in every field: as a newbee, its very difficult to distinguish wheter the HTML/CSS I look at is good or bad. Do you know any sites from which you think, as an advanced Webdesigner, that they have some great and clean HTML/CSS code to learn from?

Appreciate every tip
belehe

PS: I am not speaking about sites like CSS Zengarden, but rather real 'productive' sites like mint.com, etc...

Comment: Nice tips so far. Any further tips for regular websites? Personally, I think airbnb.com is pretty well designed. What do you think of their HTML/CSS?

Comment: I don't love that airbnb.com has so much inline JS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some "classic" links:

- [A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/): A list/magazine (because it existed before the term "blog" was generalized) with articles about every aspect of web design including semantic HTML and proper CSS use (featuring [one of the articles that started the movement against table-based design](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/journey/)).
- [CSS Zen Garden](http://www.csszengarden.com/): Created to show the designers:

  - That you can create very good designs without tables
  - That with a proper HTML layout you can change the design of your site touching only CSS and images (i.e. without having to change the HTML layout).

CSS Zen Garden has several of the most impressive and beautiful designs I have seen, definitely you should check it.

**Edit:** some examples as requested:

- [Elastic lawn](http://www.csszengarden.com/?cssfile=/063/063.css): The boxes grow with the text size, even if you don't use the zoom feature of recent browsers. That's useful if you care about the people that use big fonts in Windows.
- [Retro Theather](http://www.csszengarden.com/?cssfile=/202/202.css&page=0): Original use of absolute positioned elements (don't work in IE6).
- [Door to my garden](http://www.csszengarden.com/?cssfile=/041/041.css): Interesting effect using a fixed background.
- [New Groove](http://www.csszengarden.com/?cssfile=/065/065.css): An example of how to use decorative images for filling the leftover right space at higher window sizes.
- [Kyoto Forest](http://www.csszengarden.com/?cssfile=/207/207.css&page=0), [Ballade](http://www.csszengarden.com/?cssfile=/068/068.css), [15 Petals](http://www.csszengarden.com/?cssfile=/100/100.css), [Burning](http://www.csszengarden.com/?cssfile=/043/043.css), [Egyptian Dawn](http://www.csszengarden.com/?cssfile=/074/074.css), [Love is the air](http://www.csszengarden.com/?cssfile=/170/170.css), etc: Just like them.

Note that one of the points of CSS Zen Garden is that all the designs **use exactly the same HTML layout**, only the CSS and the background images are changed.

Comment: I checked CSS Zen Garden, but most of the designs there look like made in the 90s. You know some specific examples?

Comment: Well, the 90s look was fulfill the page with animated GIF's :-).

Comment: Ok, since you guys are so enthusiastic about the CSS Zen Garden, I will though have a closer look at it. But please, can you explain me (me as a newbee), how can I dig deeper into HTML and CSS when I always look at the same HTML layout?

Comment: OK, it's only one HTML layout but definitely you can learn a lot of CSS, since there are a lot of different designs. As I noted in the edited text the idea of CSS Zen Garden is that with one simple but well structured layout you can create almost any design. One advice that I found very useful is: create the HTML thinking about the document, and then use CSS for match your design. As a rule of thumb, if you take a look at it with all CSS disabled and you can't read it properly (e.g. title below text, sections out of order, etc.), you should change the HTML layout.

Comment: Ok, you convinced me :) I will try your approach.

Comment: @belehe I had good teachers. I used to hang out at http://www.webdesign-l.com/, I learn a lot reading and trying to answer the questions posted there.

Answer (score 6):

Study or use Paul Irish's HTML 5 Boilerplate templates for modern, practical front end code: http://html5boilerplate.com/. [Docs](https://github.com/paulirish/html5-boilerplate/wiki).

The boilerplate contains stuff like .htaccess for server-side optimization, inclusion of an ie6 png fixing script, inclusion of html5-enabling script for older browsers, and good all around techniques.

Comment: I think its a very profound collection of best practices for all aspects, but I am not sure whether I can learn a lot about how to apply different CSS techniques to obtain a certain design. Anyhow, thanks for the tip, I will try it out in my next design

Answer (score 2):

I've always thought that [CSS Zen Garden](http://www.csszengarden.com/) is a good place to get some rock solid ideas.  These guys are layout gurus.